# Jest resolve extensions

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have serveral webpack config files, let's say  `webpack.native.js` and `webpack.web.js`, each one has different resolve, where depending on the script, it will bundle with `app.native.js` or `app.web.js` into `bundle.js`.

Now with Jest + enzyme for testing, is it possible to have similar "resolve"?

The ideal would be, having `npm web:test` and `npm native:test` and it will resolve and test the corresponding platform code.

my current config: (it runs all, but it causes problem where it found some platform specific code)

```
 "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "main/shared/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!main/**/*.test.{js,jsx}",
      "!main/App.js",
      "!main/**/index.js",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["web.js", "js", "jsx"],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "main"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"

    },
    "testRegex": "(tests.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the jest setting from `package.json` into several files for the different environments and run jest using it [`config`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/cli.html#config-path) parameter.